# Strange type of scala "=>:[_, _]"

Tags: scala

I saw `"A =>: A" or "=>:[A, A]"` type signature in scalaz.

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Category.scala

I think this is some kind of scala embedded type but what's this?

Answer (score 3):

No special magic here. `=>:` is name of the type and it is a parameterized type. `A =>: A` is same as `=>:[A, A]` except the former is written in infix notation. If you are starting out with Scala then scalaz is perhaps not the best place to start.

Comment: Thanks! I started learning scala little bit ago for my fun and I thought It's time to start with scalaz but that's so early for me...

Answer (score 2):

In line [10](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Category.scala#L10) the trait `Category` specifies, that it takes a higher kinded type constructor that needs to type arguments and names it `=>:`.  Whenever you create a `Category` you have to pass that type constructor in.

You can see an example for that [here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Leibniz.scala#L44):

```
implicit val leibniz: Category[===] = new Category[===] {
    def id[A]: (A === A) = refl[A]
```

here the type constructor `===` is given as an argument to `Category`, where `===` is defined [here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Leibniz.scala#L38) as:

```
type ===[A,B] = Leibniz[⊥, ⊤, A, B]
```

Inside the category trait you name whatever is passed in as `=>:` to work with it.